# Landscape search textfield and keyboard issue

Tags: codenameone

I have a table layout. Since there are 5 columns. It is difficult to show them in portrait. So I have fixed the orientation in landscape mode. Now I have test it in devices, but here the keyboard takes almost half the screen. More frustating is the TextField height. It takes larger space and I cannot see any of the component while searching. Below is the screenshot of the problem.

[image]

Can I in any way customize the default android searchfield in landscape
mode and how to improve or customize the keyboard as well?

Answer (score 1):

At this time I don't think there is a way to disable this. I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1774) to improve this and another keyboard behavior on Android.